# How to free the dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

It's simple but I can't find the solution.

```
https://prnt.sc/q6mfb6

https://codepen.io/lastofdead/pen/WNbvXRP
```

As it appears, the drop-down menu stuck in div. What should I do to get dropdown menu out?

Comment: Please illustrate your problem by including all relevant code in the question. We shouldn't have to visit external links just to understand your problem.

Comment: I answered your question but for future note, please add all relevant code and make your question easy to answer. Even now I'm guessing what the problem is since your explanation was far from sufficient.

You  can read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Utkanos I didn't add it because the code is too long. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes. As @ObedMarquezParlapiano points out, you need to include in your question a minimal, reproducible and verifiable example. Not all of your code, just the pertinent part that will allow us to understand and diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Utkanos Okay, I got it. I'il be careful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `overflow-y: auto` from `.hastanotu` as it's preventing your div from showing the content when its height increases, and hence showing the scroll bar. By removing it you let the div flow naturally.

solution: https://codepen.io/obedparla/pen/zYxEgGY

Comment: You might need to modify your HTML and CSS further, but I can't help more since it works in the sandbox (it doesn't have all your content so I can't test the issue)

Comment: Can you look again? https://codepen.io/lastofdead/pen/WNbvXRP